# Many products with various colors, different colors & different amounts of colors

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, catalog, simple-product

I created an attribute for size since all the shirts come in the same seven sizes.

**Each shirt comes in a wide variety of colors per style, ranging from two to fourteen different colors.** *Some have 5 colors, some 8, some 10 and so on.*

Examples of products:
**All shirts come in sizes as follows: XS, SM, MED, LG, XL, XXL, XXXL**

**The shirts come in different colors and amounts of colors:**

These two have six colors, but the colors are different:

**Flag shirt** - aqua, baby blue, black, grey, red and white. (6 colors)

**Leaf shirt** - aqua, baby blue, black, bright pink, white and yellow. (6 colors)

**Magento Version 1.9.2.2**

What is the best solution to handle this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've been **mislead by the "custom options**" reference.

Custom options are different than combinations for configurable products.

> Custom options are an easy way to offer a **selection of product
>   variations that do not rely on attributes**. The limitations are that
>   you cannot track inventory based on any variation, and that a product
>   with custom options cannot be used with a configurable, grouped, or
>   bundle product. Custom options are a good solution if your inventory
>   needs are simple.

In your case you are using a size attribute so you won't need to use custom options.

**To handle your problem you need to create a color attribute that can be used for configurable products.**

Then when you create your configurable products **you need to choose both size and color when you reach the configurable attribute choice page.**

This way you can have products with same size range but different color range. That's how most retail stores based on Magento works.

You can find more information about custom options in the official documentation: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html

Comment: Thank you, Raphael, but the major problem is: 
Each shirt comes in a wide variety of colors per style, ranging from two to fourteen different colors. Some have 5 colors, some 8, some 10 and so on. Within those sets of 5, 8, 10, 14 and so on - they do not have the same colors.

Comment: @all4learning in that case you need to create your products on a style level.

Comment: @all4learning yes please edit your question with a clear example of two products with their combination of size and color

Comment: @all4learning again my solution is what you need to do. Create the flag shirt configurable product base on color and size attributes. In the associated products tab you can then choose the colors and sizes for each combination. Then do the same for each style of tshirt

Comment: I did everything you suggested and products still only show up in admin, not on website. Should I create a new question since some problems are fixed?

Comment: @all4learning yes definitely a different problem please create a new question

Comment: I created the new question and hope for a solution. New question here:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108811/magento-configurable-products-parent-does-not-import-attribute-set-via-csv Need a solution because it took two hours (once I noticed the clock) to create one configurable product by hand with Magento admin.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism If i choose Configurable product drop-down value, the price set to "0", how can i solve this error?